# What is the solution to the following Lagrange system?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> I have to maximize the function $$u(x_1, x_2) = x_1^{1/2} + x_2^{1/2}$$ in the set $$\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_1,x_2\geq0, (x_1p_1+x_2p_2) \leq N\},$$ where $p_1, p_2>0$ and $N>0$.

---

The Lagrange system is :

$1/2x_1^{-1/2}+\lambda_1-\lambda_3p_1 =0$

$1/2x_2^{-1/2}+\lambda_2-\lambda_3p_1 =0$

$\lambda_1(-x_1)=0$

$\lambda_2(-x_2)=0$

$\lambda_3(x_1p_1+x_2p_2-N)=0$

$-x_1\leq 0$

$-x_2\leq 0$

$x_1p_1+x_2p_2 \leq N$

My professor claims that the only solution of the system is: $x_1=\frac{p_2}{p_1^2+p_1p_2}N$ and $x_2=\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}N$. But I can not get that solution fro  the system. Can you help me please?

Comment: It must be $x_2=\frac{p_1}{p_1p_2+p_2^2}N$; expression for $x_1$ is correct

Comment: Could you help me understanding which is the best way to proceed to solve the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x_1,x_2$ both not zero, you immediately get $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$. You need $\lambda_3\ne0$ for the first equation to be satisfied. So the system is reduced to 
\begin{align}
\tfrac12\,x_1^{-1/2}&=\lambda_3p_1\\
\tfrac12\,x_2^{-1/2}&=\lambda_3p_2\ \ \ \ \textit{ (you have a typo there)}\\
x_1p_1+x_2p_2&=N
\end{align}
From the first and second equations you get, eliminating $\lambda_3$, 
$$
\frac1{2x_1^{1/2}p_1}=\frac1{2x_2^{1/2}p_2}.
$$
Now the system becomes 
\begin{align}
x_1p_1^2&=x_2p_2^2\\
x_1p_1+x_2p_2&=N
\end{align}
Eliminating $x_2$ we get 
$$
N=x_1p_1+\frac{x_1p_1^2}{p_2^2}\,p_2=x_1p_1+\frac{x_1p_1^2}{p_2},
$$
so
$$
x_1=\frac{N}{p_1+\frac{p_1^2}{p_2}}=\frac{Np_2}{p_1p_2+p_1^2},
$$
$$
x_2=\frac{N-x_1p_1}{p_2}=\frac{N}{p_2}-\frac{Np_1}{p_1p_2+p_1^2}=\frac{Np_1p_2+Np_1^2-Np_1p_2}{p_1p_2^2+p_1^2p_2}=\frac{Np_1}{p_2^2+p_1p_2}.
$$